# How do you minimize a function using an equality constrain and an inequality constrain together?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am having trouble minimizing a three variable function, that's because one of the constraining functions is an equality and the other is an inequality. Is it possible to minimize with such constrains?

Here is my function: $f(x, y, z)= 2\pi xy+ \pi x^2+\pi(x+1.5) \sqrt{(x-1.5)^2+z^2}$.

My constraining functions are:

\begin{align*}
y\pi(x^2)+(\pi/3)z(x^2+1.5x + 2.25) &= 2000\\
\pi x &< 20\\
x, y, z &\geq 0.
\end{align*}

I tried using the Karush Kuhn Tucker condition and the Lagrange multipliers, but I am having trouble finding a solution.

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: My attempts lead to a very messy unsolvable partial derivatives

Comment: I first tried to assume that the second constrain is satisfied and solve for the remaining Lagrange, but that led me to very a complex partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After substituting the equality constraint into the objective function, the problem can be stated as

$$
\min_{x,y}\pi  \left(x^2+2 x y+(x+1.5) \sqrt{\frac{0.911891 \left(\pi  x^2 y-2000.\right)^2}{(x (x+1.5)+2.25)^2}+(x-1.5)^2}\right)
$$

with the constraints

$$
\cases{
\frac{3 \left(2000-\pi  x^2 y\right)}{\pi  \left(x^2+\frac{3 x}{2}+\frac{9}{4}\right)}\ge 0\\
0\le x\le \frac{20}{\pi}\\
y \ge 0
}
$$

or better

$$
\cases{
x\le \sqrt{\frac{2000}{\pi y}}\\
0\le x\le \frac{20}{\pi}\\
y \ge 0
}
$$

Making a level curves plot (black) with the feasible region superimposed (blue)

[image]

we can observe the tangency of a level curve with the feasible region boundary so we follow substituting $x = \frac{20}{\pi}$ and then we minimize for $y$

$$
\min_{y}\pi  \left(\frac{40 y}{\pi }+7.8662 \sqrt{0.000333026 \left(\frac{400 y}{\pi }-2000.\right)^2+23.6799}+\frac{400}{\pi ^2}\right)
$$

obtaining $y^* = 13.6744$ etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. can it be solved without technology?

Comment: and why did we assume that when x = 20/ the function would be minimized? could you tell me the name of this method so I can learn more about it please?

Comment: The problem lacks convexity but we know that the minimum, which exists, is located far from the origin so the level curves there should be continuous and differentiable: so if the global minimum is located  outside the feasible region, then a level curve containing the global minimum should be tangent to the restriction boundary.